# Sending message result in an exception

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a message by using Javamail API, with tomcat as a webserver, but the following code resulted me in a big exception whenever I try to send the message without a file an an attachment. Although it works with messages as an attachment.

```
public static String send(String to,String body,Stringsubject,String file,String from)throws Exception{

                  if(file!=null||file!=" "){    

        File file1=new File(file);
        MimeBodyPart mb=new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource f=new FileDataSource(file1.getCanonicalPath());
        mb.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(f));
        mb.setFileName(f.getName());
        mm.addBodyPart(mb);
        }

        mb1.setText(body);
        mm.addBodyPart(mb1);
                  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        Address[] add={ new InternetAddress(to) };

              message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,add);
              message.setSubject(subject);
              message.setContent(mm);
            //message.setText(body);
              Transport.send(message);
           return "Message sent";
}
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0 (Access is denied)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:779)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at foo.SendMessage.send(SendMessage.java:57)
    at foo.Mail.doPost(Mail.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0 (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:82)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:290)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1381)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:852)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:452)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:98)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:869)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1381)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1742)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:737)
    ... 18 more
```

My question is, I've used a condition in above code before making any file as an attachment, then why I'm getting that exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(file!=null||file!=" ")` is incorrect.  I suspect what you want is `if (file != null && !file.trim().isEmpty())`.

Specifically saying `if (file != null || file != " ")` is the same as saying `if (true)` because you've used an OR operator and since `file` can't have a value of " " and null simultaneously one of those conditions is going to evaluate true, making the whole expression true.

As an aside, `file != " "` is bad form.  When testing for equality with tryings you should always use the `equals()` method, not the `==` and `!=` operators.

Answer (score 0):

The nested excpeption:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0 (Access is denied)
```

That is, you cannot access `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0`. I suggest checking your file permissions on that file. You should also tell us what the arguments to `send()` are when you get this exception.

Comment: I'm having an empty space in file variable, whenever I get that exception.

Comment: Ahh, so this comes back to Jherico's comment on the broken if clause. If the if clause was correct, i.e. && instead of ||, then your code would never try to add a file as an attachment to the message. At the moment when you're accepting "" as a filename, you're trying to add the current working directory as an attachment to your email and that results in the exception.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is the nested exception:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0 (Access is denied)

What this means is that you are not allowed to open the resource as a file.

Additionally, your test:

```
if(file!=null||file!=" "){    
    File file1=new File(file);
    …
}
```

does not test if the file actually exists or not, it only tests if the name is not null, or is not a particular string literal. A much better way to do this would be:

```
if(file!=null && !file.isEmpty()){    
    File file1=new File(file);
    …
}
```

In general, using `==` for string comparison in Java is [the wrong thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216577/common-programming-mistakes-for-java-developers-to-avoid/1216579#1216579).

For more meaningful information, you could wrap the send in a try/catch block to print out more info at that point:

```
try{
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new Exception("Debug: file:'" + file + "' from:'" + from + "'", e); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the security manager; it would throw a SecurityException if the VM is not allowed to read the file. The problem is that he's trying to open a directory with FileInputStream, which is not allowed.

Comment: @jambjo yup... fair enough, answer is updated… though I am not sure that it was incorrect enough to warrant a down-vote…